# How to fix " operands broadcasting error"

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, machine-learning, array-broadcasting

I wanted to find gradient of function wrt variable T. I am getting error operand broadcasting. Why I am getting this error and how to fix it? l takes value from 0 to 4.

```
def grad(l,d1,d2):
      grad_T = 0
      b = 1
      w = np.ones(5,1)
      w.reshape(5,1)
      T = np.random.rand(46,5)
      D = np.random.rand(46,9063)
      if(y[d2]!=y[d1]):
                difVec = D[ : ,d2].astype(float) - D[ :,d1].astype(float)
                dify = 1
                if(y[d2]<y[d1]):
                dify = -1
                grad_T = grad_T + (-1*dify*w[l,0]*difVec)/(1+np.exp(dify( 
                w.transpose() @ T.transpose() @ difVec + b )))
      return(grad_T)

    Error
    <ipython-input-40-56571fb637a5> in grad(d1, d2)
    20                 if(y[d2]<y[d1]):
    21                     dify = -1
    ---> 22                     grad_T = grad_T + 
    (-1*dify*w[l,1]*difVec)/(1+np.exp(dify * ( w.transpose() @ 
    T.transpose() @ difVec + b )))

   ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (46,) 
   (5,)
```

Comment: After the edits you made, your code still would not work. `np.ones` requires you to pass a list of dimensions. You cannot compile the code above. Refer to my answer again. Also you did not fix the issue with your `w[l, 1]`, that indexing is not possible. Finally, what is the initial shape of your grad_T? If it is (5,), your summation would not work. Because, you cannot sum two vectors of different sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to SO.

First of all your code could not be run at all. Below are the fixes to make it work. For the operand broadcasting error continue below.

```
w = np.ones(5,1)) # excess right paranthesis here
# numpy.ones([5,1]) it should be a list of dimensions
w.reshape(5,1)


T.reshape(46,5) # unnecessary


D = np.random,rand(46, 9063) # random,rand 
# You meant random.rand I suppose

grad_T = grad_T + b
    (-1*dify*w[l,1]*difVec)/(1+np.exp(dify * ( w.transpose() @ 
    T.transpose() @ difVec + b )))
# This here will not work w is [5,1] you cannot index w[l, 1]
# It is definitely out of bounds. You meant w[l, 0] I suppose.
```

I got your code working on [Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1zZi8r2NY93xzVxAuIjknWYv8alwaXGyl). And all of the dimensions of your matrix multiplications were correct. I got rid of `b` since I do not know its size. `b` is probably the culprit for the error you are getting. Your nominator is of shape (46,) and your denominator(1,) if you get rid of `b`. The error you are getting is probably because `b` has a shape of (5,). Since your w was [5,1], I suppose that your bias(`b`) is of the same dimensions. So indexing b matrix would solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks and I have made the corrections as suggested by you but still same error is coming. And the value of b = 1 and l value is from 0 to 4.

Comment: Refer to my comment. Your grad_T, possibly, is (5,) and calculated Theta is (46,) you cannot sum these two vectors. Check your gradient descent formula again.

Comment: grad_T is initialized to 0. grad_T =0 , it is here just to take the summation like sum = sum + x.

Comment: I understood. Can you copy paste your working code onto Colab and add the "Shareable link" to your question so that we can observe the code?